# How to enter a backspace character on a shell command line?

Tags: c, macos, shell

I am trying to do Exercise 1-10 in K&R. I've got the program working and running. So far I've come to know that the backspace character is cooked with the operating system. How can I input the backspace character in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what you mean by "cooked with the operating system". I guess you're asking how to enter a backspace character on the shell command line without it being interpreted as a backspace, that is, without actually erasing the previous character.

The key combination for the ASCII backspace control character is ^H (hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>H</kbd>. However, pressing this combination on the shell command line simply performs the "backspace" operation. To quote a control character in Bash, which is the OS X default shell, and in Zsh you type a combination of two characters: ^V^H.

Comment: ^H alone worked for me in a regular Ubuntu shell, but ^V^H seems to have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use (non destructive) backspace `\b` in printf and re-write. This way:

```
$ cat w.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main () 
{
    printf("abcd\n");
    printf("abc\bd\n");
}
$ ./w
abcd
abd
```

**UPDATE**
Same story using putchar():

```
$ cat w.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main () 
{
    printf("abcd\n");
    putchar('a');
    putchar('b');
    putchar('c');
    putchar('\b');
    putchar('d');
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Same output...

Comment: thank you. i appreciate it. but i am trying to do everything by using putchar()